# impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

When I used `sbt assembly` in the root dir of Spark-1.5.1 to build Spark source code on windows, after a long time,I got an error.

```
[error] (hive/*:update) java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3
```

**Spark version 1.5.1**

**sbt version I installed 0.13.9**

Anyone can help me?

logs(the second time execute `sbt assembly`)

```
[warn] Strategy 'first' was applied to 247 files
[info] Assembly up to date: D:\dev\spark-1.5.1\assembly\target\scala-2.10\spark-assembly-1.5.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar
java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.getArtifacts(IvyNode.java:809)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.getSelectedArtifacts(IvyNode.java:786)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.report.ResolveReport.setDependencies(ResolveReport.java:235)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:235)
        at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.resolve(Ivy.java:517)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:266)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:175)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:157)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:151)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:151)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:128)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:56)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:64)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:64)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:123)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:120)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:151)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:157)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1318)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1315)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$85.apply(Defaults.scala:1345)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$85.apply(Defaults.scala:1343)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1342)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1360)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1300)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1275)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (hive/*:update) java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3
[error] Total time: 200 s, completed 2016-1-25 10:49:27
```

Answer (score 3):

I was receiving this error with sbt version 0.13.8

The fix that worked for me is to edit **project/build.properties** to use **sbt.version = 0.13.9**

Comment: I don't get it, Why? This sbt version was working properly for months, and suddenly some arcane ivy-related error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error with a different project, and according to [this link](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2015), "It seems like it's related to transitive dependencies and manually added exclude introducing some kind of inconsistency."

Manually adding the dependency fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar error while running ivy and I used `ivy-2.0.0.jar` in ant/lib. By upgrading ivy.jar to `ivy-2.4.0` my problem resolved.

Here is error I caught while running my ivy task:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = junit#junit;4.4
```